# Django test runner not finding tests?

Tags: django

I am using Django 1.8. This is my project structure:

```
manage.py
/frontend
  models.py
  /tests
    test_models.py
```

And this is what `test_models.py` looks like:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from models import Section
class SectionTestCase(TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    pass

  def test_section(self):
    self.assertEqual(1, 1)
```

When I run `python manage.py test` this is what I see:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

What am I doing wrong? Or alternatively, how can I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an `__init__.py` file in your `tests/` and `frontend/` directories.